# Why won't this unittest patch work in the other method

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

My unittest patch isn't working for a method I wrote that is called in another method that I'm currently trying to unit test. I'm not sure why the patch isn't working but I think it is because the method I'm trying to patch is in the same file as the method I'm trying to test.

Please see my code below:

In the `src/main/python/storage_utils.py` file:

```
def bar(config_name):
    return SimpleDataClass(dict(read_config(config_name)))


def foo(config_name, path, file_filter, params):
    bar_info = bar(config_name)
    return
```

My unit test:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import storage_utils


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("src.main.python.storage_utils.bar")
    def test_foo_success_path(self, mock_bar):
        config_name, path, file_filter, params = 'test_config_name', 'test_path', 'test_file_filter', 'test_params'
        mock_bar.return_value = SimpleDataClass({})
        storage_utils.foo(config_name, path, file_filter, params)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as the `foo` method still goes into the `bar` method instead of mocking it and returning what's specified in the test case.

Comment: That actually worked. wtf... Can you explain?

Comment: The path you patch should be the same as if you were importing the object. Since you have `import storage_utils` your patch should match that